# How to setup build definition to update IIS settings

Tags: iis-7, build-definition, build-agent

Using TFS 2010
The solution I am working with is approximately 34 projects. I have gotten my build definition to copy the build output to a separate location. of those 34 only 3 are actually web type projects. This works fine and gives me compiled code.

My issue is that once the build is deployed to that location how to configure the build definition to update the appropriate IIS website/ settings. 
I looked at this location already but this seems quite error prone: http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.ca/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html

I considered creating a separate .msbuild for each of my csproj files that need to be setup and have it run on Post build. My suspicion though is that this will run on the build server itself and also how would I get for example the path to even update IIS with.

Anyone have any suggestions or tips to make this moderately better?

nutshell: after deploying a different location than build server how do you automate IIS processes to pickup new build.

tyvm
MacM

Answer (score 0):

You should use a deployment automation tool rather than the build tool to tackle this problem, especially if you'll be deploying to several different environments. Any deployment tool with decent IIS support will be setup to update configuration on a per-environment basis. It's the most normal IIS scenario in the world.

I think MS is including the InRelease tech in the new VS, and there are a number of other good solutions for deployment as well including [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/), and [IBM UrbanCode Deploy](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy/). .